# Storing lubridate intervals in a dataframe

Tags: r, time

I'm trying to store some intervals in a dataframe. A cut down version of the code that does this is here:

```
DateHired <- c("29/09/14", "07/04/08", "18/06/09", "09/03/15", "30/05/11", "05/11/07", "08/09/08", "30/09/13", "10/08/09", "13/08/14", "18/09/06", "21/01/08", "05/12/11", "28/06/10", "19/07/10", "05/05/14", "26/08/09", "21/04/08", "19/10/09")
TerminationDate <- c("11/06/10", "10/02/10", "06/10/09", "02/04/15", "30/06/11", "10/11/07", "17/04/14", "04/10/13", "08/02/12", "11/06/10", "03/07/09", "11/06/10", "08/08/13", "23/12/10", "20/12/13", "11/06/10", "11/06/10", "05/12/08", "01/03/10")
tenures =  data.frame(DateHired, TerminationDate, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

tenures$isoStart  <- as.Date(tenures$DateHired, format="%d/%m/%Y")
tenures$isoFinish <- as.Date(tenures$TerminationDate, format="%d/%m/%Y")

tenures$periods =  apply(tenures, 1, function(x) interval(x['isoStart'], x['isoFinish']) )
```

This ends up with this result:

```
> tenures$periods
[1] -135734400   58233600    9504000    2073600    2678400     432000  176860800     345600   78796800 -131673600   88041600   75340800
[13]   52876800   15379200  108000000 -123033600   24969600   19699200   11491200
```

When I do the same but manually. I.e.

```
> interval(as.Date("29/09/14", format="%d/%m/%Y"),as.Date("29/09/15", format="%d/%m/%Y") )
[1] 14-09-29 10:04:52 LMT--15-09-29 10:04:52 LMT
```

it gives a lubridate interval.

There are ways that I can probably solve this in other ways, but I was hoping to use the intervals in the next part of the puzzle!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
tenures$isoStart  <- as.Date(tenures$DateHired, format="%d/%m/%y")
tenures$isoFinish <- as.Date(tenures$TerminationDate, format="%d/%m/%y")

tenures$periods =  interval(tenures$isoStart, tenures$isoFinish)
```

Your date format `"%d/%m/%Y"` did not reflect the two-digit years in your data. The capital `%Y` is for four-digit years.

Also, the `interval` function is vectorized, meaning it will take the first element of each vector and create an interval, then move on to the second of each, and continue to the end.

```
head(tenures$periods)
#[1] 2014-09-28 20:00:00 EDT--2010-06-10 20:00:00 EDT 2008-04-06 20:00:00 EDT--2010-02-09 19:00:00 EST
#[3] 2009-06-17 20:00:00 EDT--2009-10-05 20:00:00 EDT 2015-03-08 20:00:00 EDT--2015-04-01 20:00:00 EDT
#[5] 2011-05-29 20:00:00 EDT--2011-06-29 20:00:00 EDT 2007-11-04 19:00:00 EST--2007-11-09 19:00:00 EST
```

---

Why didn't your first function work? Well it did work in a sense. The output is the span between the two dates, but the format/class was unexpected. Instead of the interval output, the number of seconds between the two dates were given.

For more on coercion and `?apply`:

> If X is not an array but an object of a class with a non-null dim
>   value (such as a data frame), apply attempts to coerce it to an array
>   via as.matrix if it is two-dimensional (e.g., a data frame) or via
>   as.array.

The function will work on data.frames, but with a warning that the results may not be what you expect after coercing to matrix. `lapply` is friendlier towards data frames and in this case, the function is already vectorised.